# ¿Como publicar varias aplicaciones creadas en .NET sobre un mismo puerto en iis?

Tags: .net, iis

Cree una aplicación con angular y .NET Core 6 al terminar el desarrollo la publique en una carpeta para después pasarla al servidor, hasta aquí todo bien pero el verdadero problema viene que yo quiero colocarla en el puerto 80 (Claro que desarrollare mas cosas y quisiera que todo se quede sobre el mismo puerto). Para ello investigue como realizar dicha acción cosa que me llevo a esta [información](https://informaticamadridmayor.es/tips/ejecucion-de-varios-sitios-web-de-iis-en-el-mismo-puerto-o-direccion-ip/), para esto hice todo lo que venia en la guía, hasta el punto de agregar un alias para el dns, cosa que lo hice pero al apuntar al alias me lleva a la pagina default que esta en el puerto 80 (puerto que se me facilito mas utilizar)

[image: Si llego agregar la ip me sigue redirigiendo a esta misma página]

Para esto, mejor agregue el puerto en especifico en la aplicación antes de volverla a publicar, el cual lo agregue en los archivos:

1. proxy.config.js
2. launchSettings.json

Para el proxy.config.js tiene la siguiente configuración:

```
const { env } = require('process');

const target = env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT ? `https://localhost:${env.ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT}` :
  env.ASPNETCORE_URLS ? env.ASPNETCORE_URLS.split(';')[0] : 'http://localhost:80';

const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      "/weatherforecast",
      "/Autorizadores",
      "/Trabajadores",
      "/UsuarioIngreso"
   ],
    target: target,
    secure: false,
    headers: {
      Connection: 'Keep-Alive'
    }
  }
]

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

Para el launchSettings.json tiene la siguiente configuración:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:80",
      "sslPort": 80
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "M3M_ManoDeObra": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7264;http://localhost:5264",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Y como método de comprobación ingrese el comando `donet + el nombre de la aplicación.dll`
y obtengo la siguiente configuración sobre el puerto en el que esta corriendo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces no se cual sea la manera de poder configurar lo ya que no funciona como en la guía anterior que consulte.

Comment: Por lo que entendí, tu estas dando la respuesta. El sito tiene un formato de preguntas y respuesta que tienes que respetar. Es permitido responder una propia pregunta (incluso hay un botón para ello cuando la generas), pero debes respetar el formato. Es decir arriba va la pregunta y luego en otra publicación (abajo) van las  respuestas. Y aunque, la pregunta sea autorrespondida, debe contar con toda la información necesaria para que otra persona  pueda responder de igual manera.

Comment: Listo ya modifique la pregunta y pondré la solución

Answer (score 0):

### **SOLUCIÓN**

La publicación es casi parecida, pero el detalle esta que en lugar de al momento de realizarlo es no asignarle ninguna IP, sino dejarlo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

dejarlo en IP como:  **Todas las no asignadas** y darle aceptar, aparecerá una advertencia que deben estará ocupando un puerto ya existente, no importa ya que para separarlo deben de dar clic derecho sobre el sitio y dar clic sobre la opción **Modificar enlaces...** que aquí es donde se le agregara el mismo nombre que se agrego en el DNS, pulsan modificar y debe ser igual al que en el DNS se declaro y dejarlo de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para mi yo declare ese nombre en el host, pero si lo intentan realizar, este debe de coincidir con el declarado con el dns